# Cast Java Object into Java Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, json, dictionary, casting, jetty

I am using **org.eclipse.jetty.util.ajax.JSON** to parse JSON text.
But the **JSON.parse(string)** method produces an Object and I need it as a Map.
Internally it is an object of exactly the mentioned class.
But how do you cast an Object into a Map without constructing a new one or getting the unchecked cast warning?

Currently, I have found only one solution without the unchecked cast warning, but with constructing a new Map, which is actually of course not a casting at all.

```
private Map<String,Object> getMap(String string) {
    HashMap<String,Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    Object object = JSON.parse(string);
    if (object instanceof Map) {
        Map<?,?> map = (Map)(object);
        for (Map.Entry<?,?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey().toString();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            result.put(key,value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So whether is there a way to properly cast it without unchecked cast warnings?

Comment: type-checking before type-casting might get rid of the warning.

Comment: @JanDvorak type-checking before doesn't help

Comment: @JanDvorak - Because of type erasure, you can't type check for a particular type of generic map. (For instance, you can't distinguish `Map<String,Object>` from `Map<Integer,Object>` using type checking.)

Comment: I have tried `(object instanceof Map<String,Object>)` and it doesn't work, while `(object instanceof Map)` does.

Comment: @TedHopp you can at least check it's a Map. You'll still have a `raw types` warning.

Comment: `Map<String,Object> map = (Map)(object)` - fails
`Map<?,?> map = (Map)(object)` - works

Comment: Is there a way to safely check and cast a `Map<?,?>` into a `Map<String,Object>` in Java?

Comment: @KoichiSenada no. The run time does not know generic types. There's no way of telling if an unknown `Map` maps from `String`s to `Object`s.

Comment: If you want to be type safe, you cannot add anything to the map and all you get are `Object`s.

Comment: @KoichiSenada The only safe casts are downcasts, like when you are casting from `String` to `Object`, but not from `Object` to `String`. Since every string is an object but not every object is a string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler can't guarantee that the cast is safe. Since you are the one making the guarantee, you should use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html

As @TedHopp points out, the way that library is supposed to be used is that you cast each value in the returnd `Object` to the type you know it is (but you would have to cast every property you retrieve) See the mappings here http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON.html

The point that it brings out, is that you are guaranteeing that this JSON object only contains other JSON objects (map to objects)

Therefore, if for some reason you're passed the input

```
// properties are not quoted for readability
{ a: 2, b : {c:3} }
```

Your code would fail with an invalid cast exception when you try

```
map.get("a")
```

So remember you're the one guaranteeing what goes into that string you're parsing into JSON

If you can't guarantee it, you can't create this getMap function you would like. You have to do the casting (and `@SupressWarnings`) at the place that knows what type a specific object is.

For some type safety when working with JSON, you should learn about

- http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON.Convertor.html
- http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON.Convertible.html
- http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON.Generator.html

Those classes allow you to read JSON directly into Java classes

Comment: Also see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774356/casting-from-object-in-java-without-getting-an-unchecked-warning) for what is, essentially, the same answer. Instead of suppressing warnings, you can use a non-generic `Map` and cast the return value from any `get` call.

Comment: But actually there might be cases when I can not guarantee the unchecked cast. The cast works only when the input string is within `{}`, while in other cases it might be something else than a Map.

Comment: @KoichiSenada you can only use a your `getMap` function if you can guarantee that the input is in the format `{a:{...}, b: {...}}`, that is all, the properties at the top level are JSON objects

Comment: @TedHopp, how do you use a non-generic Map without suppressing warnings?

Comment: @KoichiSenada You are asking the same question that everybody has already told you there's no way to do. See my explanation and the edits in my answer.

Comment: @KoichiSenada - Use `Map<?,?>` (or, equivalently, `Map<Object,Object>`).

Comment: @TedHopp You'll still have to cast everything when you get it out of the map.

Comment: @JuanMendes, okay, I see it is not a trivial task to make it with [Jetty JSON](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON.Output.html) then.

Comment: `Map<Object,Object> map = (Map)(object);` gives the "Unchecked assignment.

Comment: `Map<Object,Object> map = (Map<Object,Object>)(object);` gives the "Unchecked cast"

Comment: `Map<?,?> map = (Map)(object);` works fine but doesn't give the types of the keys and values.

Comment: @KoichiSenada  Here's a tutorial on upcasting and downcasting, explaing that only upcasting is safe. Any time you upcast, you're on your own, and you've been warned by the compiler (or you told it to shut up) http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50451-upcasting-downcasting/#axzz29X8Swxf4

Comment: @JuanMendes - Indeed. That's what I said in my first comment. However, you won't need to suppress warnings.

Comment: @TeddHopp I would think you would get the warnings since you need a `Map` or `String` or something else, but it's typed as `Object`

Comment: @JuanMendes, you can test if `(object instanceof Map)` and then safely downcast an Object into a Map or Map<?,?> even. But is it possible to safely downcast an object into a Map<String,Object>?