# How to cast a Map<?,?> into a typed Map in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, casting

Assume we have multiple different untyped `Map<?,?>` maps of unknown type keys and unknown type values and it is known that there are `Map<String,Object>` and `Map<Integer,Object>` maps among them.

Whether is there a way to check and distinct and safely cast them into appropriate typed maps?

Answer (score 1):

Due to type erasure, it's not possible to determine the type parameters of a generic class at runtime. However, if the maps are populated, and you know that each Map is either a Map(String, Object) or a Map(Integer, Object), you could simply inspect the first key from each Map and cast accordingly.

What's the use-case for this?

Comment: The use case was actually to cast Object into `Map<String,Object>` safely and without suppressing the warnings on unchecked casting.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927426/cast-java-object-into-java-mapstring-object]

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(((Map.Entry)map.entrySet().iterator().next()).getKey().getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.Integer")){
            System.out.println("Map<Integer,Object>");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Map<String,Object>");
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for an empty Map!

Comment: So, once I know the types of keys of every map, whether is there a way to safely cast them without suppressing the warnings on unchecked casting?

Comment: no, why are you so much bothered about this, once you are sure that this map has keys of particular type you can add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation

Comment: @zuxqoj, that special annotation makes me wondering whether is there a better approach to this goal, than suppressing those warnings.

Comment: @zuxqoj, it says my code hasn't checked before casting, so I was looking for a way to check it to satisfy the demands of the compiler.